# Alarm firing whlie app start and application destroy not as schedule

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I want to send notification every Monday at 9:00.Here is the method to set alarm which I call in onCreate of my activity. My Broadcast Receiver starts a service which will generate a notification.

```
private void testAlarm(String date) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1111, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    //set alarm every monday at 9:00
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Log.e("calender set time", calendar.getTime() + "");
    //set repeating
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
}
```

But I got notification as I start the activity and when the application is destroyed. Expecting some theory and explanation on the problem and its solution.

UPDATE
This code set alarm to previous Monday that might be the reason for notification when activity launch. But why it set alarm to previous Monday?

Answer (score 0):

Add `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);` to avoid firing the alarm immediately.